# Error in using gdal java binding

Tags: java, transformation, gdal, coordinate-systems

I am using the java binding of gdal to project a set of coordinate points from UTM to lat/log using the CoordinateTransformation Class of gdal. I have written the code as follows:

```
    SpatialReference oUTM = new SpatialReference();
    SpatialReference oLatLog = new SpatialReference();

    oUTM.SetProjCS("UTM 44/ WGS84");
    oUTM.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");
    oUTM.SetUTM(44, 1);

    oLatLog = oUTM.CloneGeogCS();

    double[] arr = new double[2];
    arr[0]=10;
    arr[1]=10;

    double x = arr[0] , y = arr[1];

    CoordinateTransformation transform = new CoordinateTransformation(oUTM,oLatLog);

    transform.TransformPoint(arr);

    System.out.println("Before:"+x+" "+y+"\nAfter:"+arr[0]+" "+arr[1]);
```

But when I run this in my main function, I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
org.gdal.osr.osrJNI.new_SpatialReference__SWIG_1()J
    at org.gdal.osr.osrJNI.new_SpatialReference__SWIG_1(Native Method)
    at org.gdal.osr.SpatialReference.<init>(SpatialReference.java:117)
    at controller.CrsConverterGDAL.main(CrsConverterGDAL.java:8)
```

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried executing your source code and I got the error

> Native library load failed.
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no osrjni in java.library.path

So just adding `gdal.jar` in your project build path is not sufficient for executing your program. There are some external native library dependencies.

Check out this link,https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3598. Here it is mentioned,

> The gdaljni.dll, ogrjni.dll, gdalconstjni.dll and osrjni.dll as well
>   as gdal17.dll and other dependant libraries must be in your path.

And in order to generate these dll for windows OS and include them in build path, steps are mentioned here, https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructions

I have not tried the steps mentioned in above link, but they seem straight forward. But if you face some issues let us know, we will try and see.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) . I fixed it by linking the native libraries. I set up the GDAL_DATA, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables in eclipses run time environment. I am using ubuntu, so they were different from what you have mentioned above. Thanks again. :)

Comment: thanks for feedback, I will edit the answer accordingly